# Python/pyaudio running on wsl2 not detecting usb mic after it's been atached to the linux subsystem with usbipd

Tags: python, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pyaudio, usbipd

I'm trying to use pyaudio with vosk to write a speech to text program, which is running on a wsl. I've attached the usb port with the mic to the wsl using usbipd, which I can see has worked as the Q9-1 mic is listed when running `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0d8c:0135 C-Media Electronics, Inc. Q9-1
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

However, pyaudio is unable to detect the mic. Running the following short script returns a mic count of 0:

```
import pyaudio
print(pyaudio.PyAudio().get_device_count())
```

Similarly, `speech_recognition.Microphone.list_microphone_names()` returns an error with ALSA lib which I assume is because it can't detect a mic.

Why is python unable to detect the mic after the usb port has been attached to the wsl, and what can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks :)